# Proof that $\dim\big(\mathcal{L}(V,W)\big)=\dim V *\dim W$, when $V, W$ are finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been looking a few proofs of this, and I have a problem with the standard one, which uses the concept of isomorphism. Suppose $\dim V=n$ and $\dim W=M$. The proof uses the function $M$ from $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ (the linear maps from $V$ to $W$), to $\text{Mat}_{m\times n}(F)$ (matrices of $m\times n$), which assigns to each linear map $T$ it's matrix $M(T)$. To do this, they fix first some basis $(v_1,....v_n)$ of $V$ and $(w_1,...w_m)$ of $W$. My problem is this fixing of the basis. Because then the function $M$ is not a function, at least not from $L(V,W)$, because each linear map has many matrices depending of the basis. How can we then state that $\dim\big(\mathcal{L}(V,W)\big)=(\dim V)(\dim W)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

*A more conceptual proof:*

Le $\mathcal B$ a basis of $V$. By definition of a basis, we have an isomorphism $L(V,W)\simeq W^\mathcal B$, so $$\dim(L(V,W))=\dim(W^\mathcal B)=\lvert\mathcal B\rvert\cdot \dim W =\dim V\cdot \dim W.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and $\left\{v_1,\dots , v_n\right\}$ and $\left\{w_1,\dots , w_m\right\}$ bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Define $L_{ij}:V\rightarrow W$ by $L_{ij}(v_k)=\delta_{ik}w_j$. Then $L_{ij}\in L(V,W)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m$. Show that any linear map $T\in L(V,W)$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of the $L_{ij}$'s. It follows that the $L_{ij}$'s are a basis of $L(V,W)$.

Now this proof indeed fixes bases at the beginning, however this is not a problem since any linear map corresponds uniquely to a matrix after choice of basis. When we have two matrices corresponding to the same linear map but w.r.t. different bases, they are linked by some matrix of base change.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, m = dim($V$) and n = dim($W$). Since $L(V,W)$ and $\mathbb{F}^{m,n}$ are isomorphic, dim $(L(V,W))$ = dim $\mathbb{F}^{m,n}$ where dim $\mathbb{F}^{m,n} = mn$ = dim($V$) dim($W$).

Answer (score 0):

Fix a basis $\beta$ of $V$ and fix a basis $\gamma$ of $W$. Now $M$ takes $T$ to its matrix $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ with respect to these bases. This is a function.